# .NET 6 Api under docker + Kubernetes & authentication

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got an ASP.NET 6 API that uses the `[Authorize]` attribute and JWT to authenticate users. Till today it was the only instance that was running on IIS. Now we've been asked to move to docker container + Kubernetes (under Azure) to scale horizontally. How can this work when running on multiple docker instances? do the authentication cookie works correctly in both instances? Or do I have to move authentication to something different from JWT?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you generating the JWT? If the signing keys are instance specific, that would create a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In multiple instances it will not work. Because, in default mode, data protection keys are tied to an instance. There are various methods to make them sharable across instances as documented in this article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0

For your deployment in Azure, best is to use Azure storage with protection through Azure Vault specifically

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
.PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("<blobUriWithSasToken>"))
.ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri("<keyIdentifier>"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```